# How to use RSpecs valid_session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm having trouble finding examples of valid_session in RSpec, and now all my scaffolded tests are broken after having added authorization.

Going through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, I'm using the authentication which is described [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out), except I'm requiring login for all pages and use 'skip_before_filter' for signin etc.

I've added a user fixture, which I've verified gets loaded:

```
userexample:
  id: 1
  name: Example Name
  email: examplename@example.com
  password_digest: $2a$10$NuWL8f2X0bXaCof3/caiiOwlF2rago7hH10JECmw1p75kEpf0mkie
  remember_token: YXjPrFfsK8SFQOQDEa90ow
```

Then in the controller spec

```
def valid_session
    { remember_token: "YXjPrFfsK8SFQOQDEa90ow" }
end
```

The code of the Session Helper

```
module SessionsHelper
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    return !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
end
```

Am I using valid_session as intended? Will supplying a remember_token with the session even work without explicitly signing in the user with sign_in? Could this be solved in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you...

```
def valid_session
  controller.stub!(:signed_in?).and_return(true)
end
```

...based on something similar that worked for me :D

```
def valid_session
  controller.stub!(:authorize).and_return(User)
end
```

Comment: Using Rails4 this didn't work for me but I found a sol'n, shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881504/rspec-controller-specs-fail-after-adding-authorization-to-rails4-application